# Yii framework, user.password is not defined

Tags: php, mysql, yii

When submitting the register form I keep getting password is not defined, I assumed it would have been defined in the cretion of the form, here is the code for my controller. Overall I want to pull the password, hash+salt it then save it to mysql DB with the rest of the data.

```
public function actionRegister() {
    $model = new Users;

    if (isset($_POST['Users'])) {

        $model->attributes = $_POST['Users'];
        $model->password-> beforeSave($model['password']);

        if($model->save()){
            Yii::app()->user->setFlash('register', 'Thank you for registering');
            $this->refresh();                                                      
        }
    }

    $this->render('register', array('model' => $model));
}

public function beforeSave() {
    if (!empty($this->password))
        $this->crypted_password = sha512($this->password);
    return true;
}
```

and here is the code in the view

```
<?php
/* @var $this UsersController */
/* @var $model Users */
 ?>

<h1>Register</h1>

 <?php $this->renderPartial('_form', array('model' => $model)); ?>
<?php if (Yii::app()->user->hasFlash('register')): ?>

<div class="flash-success">
    <?php echo Yii::app()->user->getFlash('register'); ?>
</div>
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: UPDATE I've solved that error, now just receiving a Call to a member function beforeSave() on a non-object in

Comment: yeah, exactly what i wrote in my answer ;)

Comment: Try $model->beforeSave()

Comment: @sany2k8 - no, don't try `$model->beforeSave()`, ever..

Comment: Our controllers are exactly the same @Twisted1919

Comment: @arenthor no they are not, please pay attention to the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, enable yii debugging and make sure you set `error_reporting(-1);` and `ini_set('display_errors', 1)` in your init script.

Next, password should be an attribute into your model class, for example a database table field or a public property in the model. Same goes for your crypted_password attribute.

Having this said, in your controller, you are calling `$model->password->beforeSave($model['password'])` which doesn't make any sense, unless password is a behavior attached to the Users model, which i doubt.

Leaving this aside, your controller should most probably look like:

```
public function actionRegister() {
    $model = new Users;
    if (isset($_POST['Users'])) {
        $model->attributes = $_POST['Users'];
        if($model->save()){
            Yii::app()->user->setFlash('register', 'Thank you for registering');
            $this->refresh();                                                      
        }
    }
    $this->render('register', array('model' => $model));
}
```

And in your model you could simply override the parent::beforeSave() method of Activerecord, like:

```
    protected function beforeSave() {
       if (!empty($this->password)) {
          $this->crypted_password = sha512($this->password);
       }   
       return parent::beforeSave();
    }
```

Also make sure your model attributes have proper rules so that they can be assigned via `$model->attributes = ...` way.

And that's pretty much it.

Comment: added that to my model, still getting  Call to a member function beforeSave() on a non-object in

Comment: @arenthor - because of your controller call, where you call `$model->password->_beforeSave()` which not just is wrong, but password is a string not an object!

Comment: The whole things stable but not hashing still :/

Comment: make sure password and crypted_password are part of the model rules, you can add a rule like: `array('password, cryped_password', 'safe')` so that you make sure they are bulk assigned, as i said earlier :)

Comment: added that now CStringValidator is not defined

Comment: enable yii debugging and see which line throws this error, then correct it. CStringValidator is defined, most probably something else is causing this.

Comment: says this is the line $model->attributes = $_POST['Users'];

Comment: watch the stack trace of the error, it will lead you in the model rules.

Comment: C:\xampp\htdocs\barbadosv2\protected\controllers\UsersController.php(176): CActiveRecord->__set("attributes", array("Forename" => "lee", "Surname" => "watson", "Email" => "leewatson1994@hotmail.co.uk", "Password" => "gum", ...))
171     }
172 
173     public function actionRegister() {
174     $model = new Users;
175     if (isset($_POST['Users'])) {
176         $model->attributes = $_POST['Users'];
177         if($model->save()){
178             Yii::app()->user->setFlash('register', 'Thank you for registering');
179   $this->refresh();

Comment: thats the first part highlighted in the stack trace, times like this when i wish i was programming back in java :P

Comment: update your question with the current model rules :)

Comment: added rules   *adding char count

Comment: This rule: `array('Password', 'length', 'max' => 128, 'crypted_password', 'safe'),`.... revert it as in `array('Password', 'length', 'max' => 128),` then make sure you call the setters with capitalized letters, to match your attributes, i.e: `if (!empty($this->Password)) {$this->Crypted_password = sha1($this->Password);}`...

Comment: FYI: `$_POST['Password'] != $_POST['password']`

Comment: `print_r($model->attributes); exit;` right before `$model->save()` to see what you have as attributes. i gave you enough indications, you should be able to manage it from here :)

Comment: That's all fixed now thanks, just isn't liking the Crypted_password = sha1($this->Password) part

Comment: I think I know what i'm doing with that though

Comment: Users.crypted_password is not defined?

Comment: do you have that attribute in database table? if not add it, is it Crypted_password or crypted_password? case sensitivity matters, so watch out for this, again, as i said earlier :D

Comment: Just changed it to Password and it worked WOOP!!!! Thanks for your help and patience :)

Comment: it's not like i was yelling about case sensitivity in the last 30 minutes =) you're welcome :)

Comment: Not like you had anything better to do ;P